# Calling Web service methods is the part of model or controller in MVC patterns

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, model-view-controller

As I am preparing for interviews as in iOS developer. Most of the time a question is asked is "If your are using MVC design pattern in your project and you need to write the code for calling web service like fetching user info from server. Where should you write the code 1.In Model class or controller class or some where else"

Answer (score 4):

**Its obvious model class.**

**Web request flow should be:** *The View Controller gets the web request (via buttons) from the users and send the inputs to the model. The Model will calculate and send the result back to Controller. Lastly, the controller will present the data on screen via a Display view.*

MVC:

- Model – What your application is about? (Data, Logics, Rules). All communicating code shold be written here.
- Controller – How you present your application (model) to the end users?. ViewController, its a mediator bet view and model.
- View – The interface which the end users see. Its a depecting part of app see image.

[image]

Comment: Thanks to your valuable answer